# If date > curDate returning wrong result, WHY?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Consider the following table which is similar to which I have in my db

```
team1  team2  event_date
liverp southa  2015-05-22
cryst playmo 2015-05-22
manu ashton 2015-05-22
```

If the event has not started I would like to display info about the event, however if the event has finished I would like to display message event has finished

I came up with this very simple solution

```
$curDate = date('Ymd');
$eventDateCheck=$row['event_date'];
   if($eventDateCheck < $curDate){
            echo '<h1> CURRENT ROUND ALLREADY STARTED</h1>';
    }
    else{
//do stuff
```

`$curDate` gives me correct data 2015-05-17 and event `$eventDateheck` gives me correct data 2015-05-22

Yet it still skips to event has started and not to the else part of above code? What am I missing here?

Comment: Am I missing something? Your if is `$eventDateCheck < $curDate` and you want that to be executed when you say that `$curDate  = 2015-05-17` and `$eventDateheck  = 2015-05-22`, so your if would be something like `2015-05-22 < 2015-05-17`. Does that if statement makes sense?

Comment: PHP is not human being, to understand what's in our mind, you have to compare on its way... HINT: $curDate = date('Y-m-d'); AND Use date_diff() function to solve ur problem

Comment: You need hyphens `$curDate = date('Y-m-d');` since your `event_date` column contains them. *gives me correct data* - oh? I got back `20150517` and not `2015-05-17`. Question is, as was asked already: *What am **I** missing here?*

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thank you that solved it no need to be rude though...Please elaborate what you mean  Question is, as was asked already: What am I missing here?

Comment: for crying outloud. Your question was totally unclear and you stated *$curDate gives me correct data 2015-05-17 and event $eventDateheck gives me correct data 2015-05-22* that that works? So yeah, what are we missing here?

Comment: @Fred-ii Im sorry I did a var_dump($eventDateCheck) and assumed that $curDate would be in the same format since i thought date('Ymd') returns format 2015-05-17 but I was wrong to assume and have learnt 2 lessons from asking this question, is it not partly what this site tries to achieve, helping and educating users

Comment: @Fred-ii- but thank you for your help though it is very much appreciated

Comment: You know Timothy, many people will tell you that I enjoy helping people and I'm a really funny guy, while all others will say that I am an absolute *you know what*. What you posted for code `$curDate = date('Ymd');` that told me right away that it would return the date minus the hyphens and then you stated that it was returning correct data. When questions are unclear, I post a comment rather than immediately posting an answer, because more often than none, it bites me back in the *you know what* ;-) We'll take this as a "learning curve" ;-) and you're welcome. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're comparing

```
 '2015-05-22' < '20150517'
```

Try using

```
$curDate = date('Y-m-d');
```

to get your $curDate value in the same sort of string format as used by MySQL.

Comment: *Right*, [just like I said...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30287286/if-date-curdate-returning-wrong-result-why#comment48671971_30287286). What are we missing here?

Comment: @Fred-ii-  I think the SO thing works better when answers are answers, not comments. That's why i put it in a community wiki answer.

Comment: OP obviously ignoring all comments too. [Especially mine...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30287286/if-date-curdate-returning-wrong-result-why#comment48671971_30287286)

Comment: given what the OP stated in their question: *$curDate gives me correct data 2015-05-17 and event $eventDateheck gives me correct data 2015-05-22* - is why I didn't post an answer, *per se*. Good move on the wiki ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert them to a comparable format (like a timestamp), with **strtotime(string $time)**, which will "Parse about any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp."

In your case this will be something like:

```
if(strtotime(date('Y-m-d')) > strtotime($row['event_date']))
{
    // do somehting
}
```